# Yii composite key in relatins with custom params

Tags: activerecord, yii, has-many, composite-key, relation

I want to use composite key in ActiveRecord.
I got two tables.

Quotes and Comments.
Quotes contains pk - **id**;
Comments pk is composite - **module**, **section**, **cid**

**module** - module name, where comments come from.

**section** - section of this module

**cid** - identificator, in this situaction this is id of quote.

In comments I defined primary key like so.

```
public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('module', 'section', 'cid');
}
```

Next one, I want to get those records, what related to quotes.
So, in Quotes I declared relation:

```
'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'module, section, cid', 'params' => array(
                ':ypl0' => '"quotes"',
                ':ypl1' => '"quote"',
                ':ypl2' => 'id'
            )),
```

The required result is:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes q

LEFT JOIN comments c ON (c.cid = q.id AND module = "quotes" AND section = "quote")

WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

SQL is working, relation - not. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following untested code

```
'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'cid','condition'=>'module=:param1 AND section=:param2','params' => array(':param1' => 'quotes',':param2' => 'quote',)),
```